# ZeroMQ in request-replay pattern allow request comming from specific ip only

Tags: c, zeromq, distributed-system

How to allow request coming from specific IP address only in 0MQ request-reply pattern.
I don't want to receive request from any other IP address. I want to communicate only between two IP address first one is request maker and second one is reply maker.

request.c

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *requester = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REQ);
    zmq_connect(requester, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");

    char buffer[10];
    printf ("Sending Hello\n");
    zmq_send(requester, "Hello", 5, 0);
    zmq_recv(requester, buffer, 10, 0);
    printf("Received: %s\n", buffer);

    zmq_close (requester);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);

    return 0;
}
```

reply.c

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(void) {
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *responder = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REP);
    int rc = zmq_bind(responder, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
    assert(rc == 0);

    char buffer[10];
    zmq_recv(responder, buffer, 10, 0);
    printf("Recived: %s\n", buffer);
    sleep(1);
    zmq_send(responder, "World", 5, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336954/0mq-get-message-ip it is impossible. Do not use 0MQ and use other tool.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will use other took.

Comment: Normally, you'd use a firewall to limit access to network services. That might be a better way ahead, rather than trying to bend ZMQ or something else to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

> From [stackoverflow.com/questions/20336954/0mq-get-message-ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336954/0mq-get-message-ip) it is
> impossible. Do not use 0MQ and use other tool.